# View changed files in Xcode 4.2 SCM features

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

How can I see all the files that have been modified in Xcode 4.2 like in Xcode 3.2.6 there was a separate SCM view which shows all the files that have been changed in a single place. In Xcode 4.2 I can see the modified files scattered over my project pane. I want to specifically check in some files and want to see all the modified files at a single place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottom left, click on the thing that looks like a little box, next to the clock.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the bottom left hand corner there's an icon for "show items with source control status".  It will filter the file list to files that have a status (modified, added).

[image]